# Rubber rings for attaching lights etc

Tags: accessories

I have some lights and a cycle computer that attach using some sort of rubber or silicone bands (or O rings - don't know what they are called). I need some replacements, but I don't know what they are called!

Best I can find on (say) Amazon are O rings that look the same but seem to be only for plumbing - not long term daily use on a bicycle.

I need various sizes as I want to move stuff between bikes - which have differing tube/handle bar diameters.

The technically right name - or a recommended supplier - would be most welcome!

Comment: You can get a set of common plumbing o-rings for not much money in a shop selling plumbing supplies. They work quite well, but aren't as stretchy as the ones that come with the lights, so you need to be a little more careful choosing the size.

Comment: Depending on the length, consider shopping in the ladies' hair care aisle of your local drug store or department store.  I found some nice silicone-like hair bands that are maybe 5" in circumference, perhaps 3/16" thick, and quite stretchy.  Very durable too.

Comment: Easy to find on EBay - go to bicycles/lights section and type in 'ring'.  O Rings - the ubiquitous rubber rings used in everything are not as stretchy so you need to get a closer sized fit and won't last as long, but are available at any auto or hardware shop. O Rings also don't have the little tag making it easy to take the light off.

Comment: I have recently acquired a Garmin device with such mounting bands, and having also used various O-rings for purposes of attaching various things, I can say for sure, they are not the same exact material. The Garmin ones are much more resistant and much more stretchy. Indeed a common O-ring could do the job, but I doubt it will last as long, so don't use them as your only anchoring item. My device came with a stretchy "lanyard" that could help prevent loosing the item completely in case then main bands break off, so I always use it for redundancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## They are usually referred to as O-Rings

Typing O ring bicycle into Google will give you plenty of options.

Depending where in the world you are would depend on where you can get them from in the UK you can get them from Halfords or LBS.

[Here](https://www.cyclesurgery.com/p/cateye-rapid-x-bands-P5144096.124.html?gclid=CNvri8aHx9ICFUafGwodaT8EfQ&gclsrc=aw.ds) are some from Cateye

[Here](https://www.evanscycles.com/garmin-replacement-bands-for-quarter-turn-bike-mount-00103984?esvt=51830-GOUKE1546030&esvq=&esvadt=999999-0-829256-1&esvcrea=99160881296&esvplace=&esvd=c&esvtg=pla-168938793416&esvo=00103984-NA-NA&esvaid=50080&gclid=CPex_OuHx9ICFYg_Gwod_EoC2A) are some from Garmin

[Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/slp/bicycle-light-rubber-band/qukwgcneuwa56bf) have a variety of different bands

I doubt materially the ones from a hardware store would be much different but the cycling ones would be designed to go around the standard handlebar / stem diameters. It might therefore be a bit hit and miss with some from a hardware store, i.e. too small, too big, not stretchy enough.

Comment: Are these any different than what you would find in the [plumbing section](http://www.homedepot.com/p/15-O-Rings-10-Pack-96732/100309239) of the hardware store?  Seems like it would be cheaper and easier to get the same thing at the hardware store if they are indeed the same thing.

Comment: @Kibbee no idea, I'm not a plumber. I doubt materially they would be much different but the cycling ones would be designed to go around the standard handlebar / stem diameters. Might be a bit hit and miss with some from a hardware store.

Comment: The hardware store ones might not last as long (thinner & less stretchy, so prone to cracking), but I'm more likely to lose than break them anyway and I'm sure I'm not alone in that.  So I'd go for the cheaper option, but in a variety pack (and have) (@Kibbee)

Comment: O-rings are industrial & normalized items. I doubt that any accessory providing companies have their own production line. https://www.globaloring.com/Downloads/International_O-ring_Size_Standards.pdf

Comment: My goto place for such things would be ebay or aliexpress. Search for "O-Ring rubber bicycle".

Answer (score 5):

Have you thought about cutting an old inner tube across its length. Various thicknesses of cut give more or less stretch. Rubber versus latex, too many different size tubes to mention. Cheap as chips and your LBS will have an endless supply.

Comment: Interesting... and if the tube is too narrow, cut it at an angle. If you already have a cut and it's too long, wrap it around 1 1/2 times. Moreover, it has been made to a rigorous standard, and you once trusted it with your life during your top speed downhill, and so it's surely good enough for your cadence counter.

Comment: Pro road race teams use cut up latex tubes to attach timing chips to their bikes. However, I struggle to see how this is a direct replacement for an O-ring. The cut tube will wrap over the timing chip entirely. The O-rings fit over hooks on the computer or light. Unless you meant to cut  the tube as if it were a cut rubber band, then tie it?

Answer (score 0):

O-rings made of Silicon/Silicone are typically orange in color. Are your o-rings orange? Are these use in a outdoor application?

Reason I ask is typical o-ring you will find in home depot or a plumbing supply house are OK they will crack over time due to ozone exposure.

Neoprene or silicone o-rings work best for those types of applications.  You can purchase small quantities from the company here at https://www.alliedmetrics.com/seals/o-rings/

Comment: welcome to SE.  Do you have any affiliation with the linked site?  If so please add that with the Edit link.   If you have a moment please browse our [tour] to learn some of these other minor points about how SE works.